# Grant login access to a Support Organization - monitor their page views using Event Logs

Tags: event-monitoring, installedpackage

We have an organization with sensitive data. If I grant login access to an installed package vendor, we want to monitor which pages they visited as they diagnose the issue

- We also have Salesforce Shield Event Monitoring

So, is the following true?

- If I grant login access to the installed package vendor where my userId = `005xxxxxxxxxxx`
- That any page views done by the ISV will be recorded as [URI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_uri.htm) and [Lightning Page View](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_lightningpageview.htm) events where the UserId field in those events will be the same as my userId `005xxxxxxxxxxx`
- And that I can distinguish the page views visited-by-the-ISV versus visited-by-me by using the event log record's IP address.

Just checking to see if there's an easier way to locate the visited-by-ISV pages.

Comment: Since you already have "Salesforce Event Monitoring", this becomes seamless.   You may be able to distinguish the "foot print" of the ISV /support user, via the IP address logged in (assuming it is different from yours) OR the time of login (if it is distinct from yours).     Please check the "Login Event " type and "Login As Event" type under EventLogFile.   I could not find a flag or indicator, to distinguish the login via "grant login".   But , there are other details, which can help you narrow down the latter's login.